# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular2-formbuilder

I am making an anonymous formArray input(autocomplete) to find item by using `autocomplete`.

After adding an autocomplete, the autocomplete input doesn't work though it works fine independently.

The error message is  `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'orderItems -> 0 -> search'`

Could you help me improve the codes?

Thank you.

```
 <form [formGroup]="orderForm">
    <div formArrayName="orderItems">
      <div *ngFor="let orderItem of getControls(); let i = index" [formGroupName]='i'>
        <p-autoComplete
        formControlName="search"
        (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"
        [suggestions]="list">
        </p-autoComplete>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p-button (click)="onAdd()"> add </p-button>
</form>
```

```
public orderItems = new FormArray([])
public orderForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
      'orderItems': this.orderItems,
      search: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });

    this.orderForm
    .get('search')
    .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === '') {return null};
      this.getList(value)
    })
}

  getControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.orderForm.get('orderItems'))
    .controls;
  }

  get search() {
    return this.orderForm.get('search') as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: The control 'search' is independent from 'orderItems'. Your autocomplete is inside of a ngFor that iterates over each orderItem. When inside of the iteration, you should access items contained within the object of orderItem. Basically, 'search' doesn't exist inside of orderItems.

Comment: @BrianSmith Thanks, Brian. Well noted. I thought the autocomplete is contained because it is inside of ngFor. So could you help me the codes working?

Comment: Can you set this up in a stackblitz and I will fork it.

Comment: @BrianSmith Thanks you so much. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-somt3x?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your stackblitz wouldn't compile for me and had too many errors. I put this together as a example of how to set up the form array with a search control and put a control on the page. It should get you in the right direction. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-control?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your form initially with an empty array

```
buildForm() {
    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
      orderItems: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }
```

Then get the data for the array and populate the array

```
setOrderItemArray() {
    const orderItemsArray = this.orderForm.get('orderItems') as FormArray;
    this.orderItemsList.forEach(item => {
      orderItemsArray.push(this.buildOrderItemsForm(item))
    });
  }

  buildOrderItemsForm(item): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: item.id,
      search: item.search,
      name: item.name
    })
  }
```

Now you have an instance of 'search' in each object of the array and can use search autocomplete independently for each.

Comment: I'm still getting the error so for me it don't works.